# Get list of visible elements in WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

[image: Example TreeView Structure]

I'm trying to find a good way to get the visible elements in a WPF TreeView in C# at any given point in time. For instance, in this case, I would expect to have: Brazil, Canada, Small Stock, Tarte au sucre, Tourtiere, Big stock, Denmark.

Most of my research has led me to believe that I need to iterate over all items and see if they are visible individually. Is there a better inbuilt method I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, there is not a "inbuilt" method to check if all parents and childen are expanded, only after iterating over them you can check their properties.

This should do the trick to get all the children on any expanded parent, and their respective parent added to a list.

```
List<TreeViewItem> expandedTVI = new List<TreeViewItem>();
foreach (TreeViewItem item in treeView1.Items)
{
    if (item.HasItems && item.IsExpanded) //if it has children, and the parent is expanded
    {
        foreach (TreeViewItem child in item.Items)
            expandedTVI.Add(child); //add the child to the list
    }

    expandedTVI.Add(item); //always add the parent to the list
}
```